# Does Arya purposely lead the Waif into a trap?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In a great [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nffJ-Tcu9CE) from [*No one*](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/No_One) (8th episode of 6th season), Arya is being chased by the Waif, and

> Arya finally manages to kill the Waif. She achieves this by leading the Waif to Arya's hiding place, where Arya keeps her sword Needle. She then cuts the candle off, and taking advantage of her better skills at fighting in the dark, is able to defeat the Waif.

As Arya, wounded, is running away, with her blood-covered hand she touches quite a few stone walls. This may be because she is weak from her wounds and needs to lean on the walls in her run. Or it could be that she is *leaving a trace on purpose* so as to lead the Waif where Arya thinks she can defeat her.

**Does she leave the blood trace on purpose or not?**

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147562/46677)

Answer (score 11):

### Yes

### The Prep

As you can see in the scenes and episodes leading up to that point, Arya starts training in her 'room' in the dark. She turns off her candle and practices with Needle. Seeing in the dark is not an easy task and takes a lot of getting used to, Arya has essentially trained her eyes to become accustomed to the dark, allowing them to adjust rapidly.

Additionally, Arya has spent a fair amount of time 'blind', and has had ample time to become comfortable not 'seeing' with her real eyes.

### The Setup

In comes the setup; in the 'parkour' event where Arya is running away from the Waif, Arya makes it to her 'room', with only minor injuries. At which point, she blows out the candles in the room, making it completely dark.

You can see it all happening in this scene from the episode *No One* (Season 6, Episode 8):

### The trace

At this point, it is not important whether or not Arya left the blood traces on purpose, she knows that the Waif is a proficient killer, and would find her in one way or another.

It's unclear from the video if Arya intended to leave the blood trail, especially given that the scene was filmed in a way to make the viewers be tricked as well.

Comment: _At this point, it is not important whether or not Arya left the blood traces on purpose_ Well, my question was exactly that :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo You might want to edit your title then. The title and the question in the body are asking two different things. I believe Mooz has answered "Does Arya lead the Waif into a trap"...

Comment: @Skooba How are they different? To me, "lead" implies "on purpose". Is it so? I'm not a native English speaker

Comment: @LuisMendo As this answer shows the two questions can have different answers.

Comment: @Skooba I replaced "try to" by "purposely" in the title. I hope it's clearer now. Thanks

Comment: @LuisMendo What I am trying to get at is the same as this answer, we don't know if the blood had anything to do with it, but a trap was being laid. Your title question can be answered with a "yes", your body question not so much.

Comment: Ah I see. Not sure if it's worth changing the title again...?

Answer (score 4):

She leads The Waif to her "lair" on purpose.

Arya knows she cannot win out in the public **and** unarmed. That is probably the most important reason why Arya is going to her lair, to get Needle and stick her with the pointy end.

The scene where she wipes blood on the wall is also clear, she wipes the blood on the wall, she does not lean on the wall for support. She is injured and it probably does hurt, but the action she takes there is very clearly a wipe on the wall, if you are hurt and need support, you also do not tend to leave your hand behind you.

The scene right before it also shows Arya pausing when she enters the darker area, to let her eyes adjust.

Comment: This seems plausible, but any official information to back it up? I've tagged the question with the book as well, in case it's clearer there

Comment: @LuisMendo I don't think the books are at that point yet. (but i could be wrong)